# Airbnb short link to full link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm working on an app that references and uses Airbnb links as input. There are 2 types I've found:

1. Long form, e.g.: https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/47074377 This is what people use from desktop.
2. Short form, e.g.: https://abnb.me/YEO24YyMisb. These are often what people share from mobile devices.

My javascript code can handle (1) just fine because I can easily find the substring of the last slash after "rooms" in order to get the PropertyID = 47074377 and make subsequent API calls.

But I cannot figure out how to get the propertyID from (2). I need this ID in order to make API calls.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Seems like you can just follow the redirect that you get when requesting the short form.

Comment: You can use an API. Such as [unshorten](https://unshorten.me/api)

Answer (score 0):

From @c0mit1 -- https://unshorten.me/api this worked! Simply call this with the API you want to unshorten.